# RadGridView Top Header Title - Telerik Winforms

Tags: winforms, telerik

How can I set a header title on top of RadGridView?

[image]

Comment: Would a simple label can do the trick or you need something a simple label can't do ?

Comment: I need the header attach to the grid for docking purposes.

Comment: @Stranger, vertical `SplitContainer` maybe? header goes into top panel, grid goes into bottom. And dock Container itself

Comment: Why does not exist a built-in feature for radgridview?